# Using a Rust-based WASM module in a CRACO project

Tags: reactjs, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, craco, wasm-pack

I am working on a project originally created with Create React App (CRA), that I eventually switched over to using CRACO due to the need to handle some LESS files. I am now trying to integrate a separate WebAssembly project that exports a struct that I would like to use in the react project. I wrote bindings using wasm-bindgen, and published the result with wasp-pack as an npm module (bundler build). That produces an NPM package that I published.
Next I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/nicolasrannou/wasm-in-create-react-app-4-in-5mn-without-ejecting-cf6) that uses CRACO and imports the wasm code from a library. Essentially the code is the same on the react end, but I have a struct that should be wrapped instead of a function. However it doesn't work as expected. When running, I get an error below:

```
./node_modules/@my_scope/my_pkg/my_pkg_lib_bg.js
Attempted import error: '__wbg_jsmystruct_free' is not exported from './my_pkg_lib_bg.wasm' (imported as 'wasm').
```

I am not exactly sure what might be causing this specific error (whether that is some issue in webpack, craco, the wasm wrappers, or some combination of the above). If there would be any additional info that would be useful, I would be happy to provide it. Thanks for all the help!